# How to find flow equation of a complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, vector-fields

> [image]
> Page-199 of VDG

I'm trying to figure out how to get the dipole flow equation as shown in the above picture from the complex function $f(z)=z^2$. I write it in components and get:

$$ u= x^2 - y^2$$

$$ v= 2xy$$

Now, how do I use this to find the integral curves?

Comment: Could you give more detail on what are $\mathcal{J}(z^2)$, $u$ and $v$?

Comment: Oh that. That is like not important but it essentially is the index of $z^2$. How much rotation $z^2$ experences as we move around the unit circle evaluating at each point

Comment: Oh right, I thought that was some fancy thing related to the imaginary part or something. So essentialy, you are looking for the integral curves of the vector field $X(z) = z^2$, is that it?

Comment: Yes I want to know how to derive those dipole field lines @Didier

Answer (score 3):

The integral curves of the system

$\dot x= u=x^2-y^2$ and $\dot y = v=2 xy$

can be found by first expressing the system in consolidated form as a single condition on complex quantities:
the complex velocity vector $ \dot z= \dot x+ i \dot y $ must be identicalto $ u+ iv=f(z)=z^2$ at each instant, hence $ \dot z=  \lambda(t) z^2$  where $\lambda(t)=1$ at each time.

Separating variables and integrating, deduce that  $ \int \frac{ dz/dt }{z^2} \ dt= - z^{-1}(t) + z^{-1}(t_0)  = t- t_0$
This can be solved for $z(t)$ to obtain a parametrization of each integral curve in terms of its initial position $z_0$.

More succinctly,  the imaginary part of  $- z^{-1}(t) + z^{-1}(t_0) $ must vanish, and this gives an implicit equation for the family of all such integral curves. Looking at the diagram it looks like you might choose $z_0$ to lie always on the imaginary axis to generate a one-parameter family of such integral curves: $ \Im( z^{-1})= C$. That is, $y= C (x^2+y^2)$ which describes a family of circles centered on the $y$ axis, all passing through the origin.

Comment: What is the idea behind setting dz/dt=z^2

Comment: That's what integral curve means.

Comment: Thanks for the help tho

Comment: I understood integral curves conceptually as the curves resulting from flowing on the vector field but I don't understand how that equation realizes that concept @TedShifrin

Comment: Look up the definition of the flow of a vector field?